# .NET Core Github Actions MSBuild Error MSB4044

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, github-actions

I have the following github Actions script to deploy to NuGet:

```yaml
name: NuGet Publish

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*' # Specify the tag pattern, e.g., 'v1.0.0'
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      id: cacheStep
      with:
        path: ~/.nuget/packages
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Setup NuGet.exe for use with actions
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5
    - name: Restore NuGet
      if: steps.cacheStep.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      run: nuget restore Octane.sln
    - name: Set VERSION variable from tag
      run: echo "VERSION=${GITHUB_REF/refs\/tags\/v/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build OctaneEngine/OctaneEngine.csproj --no-restore --configuration Release /p:Version=${VERSION} /p:AssemblyVersion=${VERSION}
    - name: Publish NuGet package
      run: dotnet nuget push OctaneEngine/bin/Release/*.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key ${{ secrets.NUGET_API_KEY }} /p:Version=${VERSION}
      env:
        NUGET_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NUGET_API_KEY }}
```

This code is failing on the build step and giving me the the error:

> MSB4044: The "GenerateDepsFile" task was not given a value for the required parameter "AssemblyVersion

I tried manually specifying this in the script as well but it still isn't resolved. I have GenerateAssemblyInfo disabled in the .csproj file and have a default assembly version of 1.0.0.0 defined.

Comment: You're referencing the variable with the wrong syntax. `${VERSION}` should be `$(VERSION)` or `$env:VERSION` assuming the default shell is pwsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a Windows runner (`windows-latest`) with its default shell i.e. [pwsh](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) (PowerShell 7.2.17 as of now). You should use commands under the `run` sections that are supported by the respective shell of the runner you're using.

The following [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2#using-the-variable-syntax) is used to access the environment variables under PowerShell:

```
$Env:<variable-name>
```

You need to update the syntax for all the environment variables in your workflow:

- `$GITHUB_REF` => `$Env:GITHUB_REF`

  - Better yet, you can use [`GITHUB_REF_NAME`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) instead i.e. `$Env:GITHUB_REF_NAME`
  - Also, you can use [`TrimStart("v")`](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) to trim that `v` prefix
- `$GITHUB_ENV` => `$Env:GITHUB_ENV`
- `$VERSION` => `$Env:VERSION`

---

After incorporating these changes, your steps would look like this:

```yaml
- name: Set VERSION variable from tag
  run: |
    $VERSION=$Env:GITHUB_REF_NAME.TrimStart("v")
    echo "VERSION=$VERSION" >> $Env:GITHUB_ENV

- name: Build
  run: dotnet build OctaneEngine/OctaneEngine.csproj --no-restore --configuration Release /p:Version=$Env:VERSION /p:AssemblyVersion=$Env:VERSION

- name: Publish NuGet package
  run: dotnet nuget push OctaneEngine/bin/Release/*.nupkg --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --api-key $Env:NUGET_API_KEY /p:Version=$Env:VERSION
  env:
    NUGET_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NUGET_API_KEY }}
```